# Confusion when importing Django' generic class based views

Tags: python, django, python-import, django-class-based-views

While exploring the reference documentation and some tutorials I have seen the import for Django's generic class based views used in multiple ways:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView
```

Or:

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
```

I have tried experimenting with both tactis and they both seem to work, yet the first option seems less correct.

Do all the generic CBVs also exist within  the generic module a well as the submodules? Can Python import classes from submodules by only importing a higher module? What is actually happening here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging it seems that within **django.views.generic.__init__.py** all the other generic CBVs are imported allowing intentional access to them within **django.views.generic**. This seems to be the standardised way of importing the generic CBVs.

Answer (score 0):

Django like Python says that you need to be explicit and specific,  you will find in the official documentation that the way Django import all generic views are as follow :

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView
```

When reading this line you understand that you are import generics view and only one in particular.

From the documentation regarding imports :

> Whenever possible, be as explicit as possible with imports.

I would say all are fine except the last one, this bad pratice regarding the PEP8

Comment: Apologies that was an unintentional error in the last code snippet (I have updated to the corrected version). I am still confused whether to import from just views.generic or views.generic.list/views.generic.display etc.